# Formulário em PHP está enviando mensagens duplicadas

Tags: php

Estou com um formulário para envio de e-mails e apesar do mesmo estar funcionando - no quesito envio da mensagem - ele apresenta um problema onde ao receber essas mensagens no e-mail do destinatário, ela vem duplicada.

Uma mensagem chega normal com os campos todos preenchidos e a outra vem com os campos em branco.

Podem me ajudar no que pode estar acontecendo?

O código é esse abaixo:

```
<?php
  ini_set("SMTP", "localhost");
  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
  $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

  $dpto = "faleconosco@dominio.com.br";
  $Titulo = "MENSAGEM ENVIADA PELO FORMULÁRIO DO SITE";
  $Destinatario = "$dpto";
  $mensagem1 = "
  Nome: $nome
  E-mail: $email
  Telefone: $telefone
  $mensagem";
  mail("$Destinatario","$Titulo","$mensagem1","From:$email");
?>
```

Comment: Como você esta chamando este código? esta usando ajax? ou um formulário simples?

Comment: Oi Wictor.  Estou usando um formulário simples:
<form action="<? $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="POST">

Comment: O PHP em si está funcionando corretamente, fiz um teste aqui e recebi o mail certinho.

Comment: Verdade Leo ... está certinho.  Só não entendo porque recebo a mensagem duplicada

Comment: então, não é nada com o PHP, eu não recebi duplicado

Comment: Tente substituir $PHP_SELF por $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]

Comment: Vou ver então fora do PHP o que pode ser.  Muito obrigada Leo por fazer o teste e pelo seu retorno !!

Comment: Obrigada Wictor !!

Comment: mesmo que essa variável  $PHP_SELF não tenha sido  declarada, o código funciona do mesmo jeito

Comment: Pode sim @LeoCaracciolo.  Mais tarde vou ver melhor o que pode ter sido e deixo resposta aqui da solução.  Obrigada mais uma vez !!

Comment: Fernanda, qual a forma de verificação que vc usa para entrar nesse código do envio? (Por ex., `isset` para ver se as variáveis vindas do formulário estão com dados).